# Facing problems in Setup for OpenGrok

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, opengrok

I am trying to install OpenGrok in my ubuntu. I was following the steps described here 
http://blog.vinceliu.com/2008/06/installing-opengrok-on-ubuntu-linux.html

but at one point I got stuck, when I giving following command 
"java -Xmx1524m -jar ./bin/opengrok.jar -W /opengrok/configuration.xml -P -S -v -s /opengrok/source -d /opengrok/data"

I am getting the

Exception: org/apache/commons/jrcs/rcs/ParseException
14 Jun, 2012 12:15:21 PM org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.Indexer main
SEVERE: Unexpected Exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/jrcs/rcs/ParseException
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.history.RepositoryFactory.(RepositoryFactory.java:41)
    at org.opensolaris.opengrok.index.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:421)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.jrcs.rcs.ParseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 2 more

So can any one help me in this error, I tried to find out the jar for this exception, but I didn't find any. So tell me where to get the jar and where should I put that jar to make it compile.

Comment: I found out that there is problem with opengrok0.11 so install older version it is working fine. If anyone else need to install it refer my blog http://rahulonblog.blogspot.in/2012/06/opengrok-installation-guide.html